# Table of Contents not properly displayed when adding a prefix to sections

Tags: table-of-contents

I have an issue with the table of contents when I add the following entry:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{WT~\arabic{chapter}-\arabic{section}}
```

... and here's the image illustrating the issue I am facing--any idea how I can increase the space between the WT  and the title?
[image]
I generate the table of contents with just a `\tableofcontents`

PS: I am a latex newbie. I did try to use packages such as the `titlesec`, `titletoc` but I couldn't figure out the latter.  I still need time to absorb and adjust my state of mind to meet latex's :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width of sectioning number for each level (or type) of contents line (often called the "numwidth") is fixed. For sections, it is `2.3em` in `book` and `report` standard classes.

The easiest way to change the "numwidth" for sections is probably to use `tocloft` package:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{WT~\arabic{chapter}-\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\cftsecnumwidth{4em}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{title}
\section{title}
\section{title}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you kindly for the solution and the explanation!